# Cisco VPN stops Windows 7 Browsing

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

My browsing and other 'internet' activity (dropbox,digsby etc) halts when I connect to a VPN session using Cisco Systems VPN client Version 5.0.04.0300 on Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit on my Dell XPS M1530.The only option left for me at this time is to use my vpn network proxy to enable the connection back.

I tried doing the ucheck "Use default gateway on remote network" solution as mentioned on a previous post [Windows 7 VPN stops web browser](https://superuser.com/questions/31027/windows-7-vpn-stops-web-browser/31038#31038) but I don't see that option on the properties of "Cisco systems VPN adapter" connection properties.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From Cisco's [Understanding the Cisco VPN Client](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client46/win/user/guide/vc1.html):

> **Browser proxy configuration for Internet Explorer**
>
> When connecting to the secure gateway
>   at a central location, the VPN Client
>   changes the web browser proxy to
>   accommodate the organization's
>   environment. When disconnecting, the
>   software returns to the user's default
>   browser application. This feature
>   applies to Internet Explorer only. The
>   VPN Concentrator administrator
>   configures this feature in the VPN
>   Concentrator Manager (see VPN Client
>   Administrator Guide, Chapter 1).

The solution is either to ask the VPN server's admin to turn off this option, or to use another browser than IE, for example Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I have same problem as OP, but on my system all direct Internet connection is gone. Outlook, Firefox, everything.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: In your case the Cisco VPN client maybe creates a compulsory tunnel. The type of the tunnel is dictated by the admin of the VPN server to which you connect. Compulsory tunnel will cut off any other access to any external computer, including the LAN.

Comment: @harrymc But I can use connect to computer on the LAN with no problems. Anyway, could you post a link to some documentation about that? Company's IT staff has no idea how to disable this behavior and it is seriously decreasing productivity.

Comment: @harrymc: I use Shrewsoft's VPN client, not a Cisco client, any idea on how I turn off the use default gateway option ?

Comment: @AndrejaKo: The Cisco doc is probably named "Allow Split Tunneling for VPN Clients on your-cisco-model". Call Cisco support if the IT staff can't find it.

Comment: @Sathya: Sorry, can't help on Shrew Soft.

Comment: Alright @harry no probs

Comment: @Sathya: Having the software to test, you might make sense of these links: http://www.shrew.net/static/help-2.1.x/files/%7B3F3A9BCC-F89F-43F8-817D-09CB3A17D3D8%7D.htm#SplitTunnelConfiguration and http://www.shrew.net/static/help-2.1.x/files/%7B7C451822-AD0C-42BA-A497-B2D1FABB6CF0%7D.htm#AutomaticPolicyConfiguration and http://www.shrew.net/static/help-2.1.x/files/%7B7C5B5EA5-E69C-487D-A796-524192188FC7%7D.htm#SplitNetworkConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

When a remote user connects to the a secure gateway, the VPN Client can receive a web browser proxy setting from the secure gateway and then change the web browser proxy configuration of the user to operate within the organization's environment. This setting is in effect only while the user is connected to the secure gateway. When the user disconnects, the VPN Client automatically changes the browser proxy of the PC to its original setting.

Answer (score 0):

The Latest version of cisco vpn won't allow internet connection either if it's IE/Firefox/Chrome or any other browser, you wont be able to connect to internet due to fact it blocks 80 port, BUT some ports would work such that application which uses high range ports such as torrent clients, online game software's which uses specific ports !!